# A migrated question should get its 'asked time' reset

Tags: feature-request, migration

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541978/match-mysql-wildcard-entries-in-table-to-query) was just migrated (~50 minutes ago as of asking this question) to Stack Overflow from superuser.com. For a brief period after it was migrated, it appeared on the "Newest" tab of the MySQL questions page. On subsequently refreshing that page the question was no longer visible - a little hunting showed that it had been sorted according to its original asking date of April 1 and could now be viewed on page 58 of the "Newest" MySQL questions. It seems this defeats the purpose of migrating the question, as many users might not get to see it.

It seems that questions that are migrated should have their asking time (at least for the site they are migrated to) updated to the time at which they were migrated so that they can remain on the first page of the "Newest" question list for as long as a question that was asked at the same time. That will allow maximum chance of the question being seen after it is migrated and hopefully getting an answer.

Comment: MSE dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279313/could-migrated-questions-use-the-migration-date-as-the-asked-date

Comment: @SamuelLiew indeed that is the exact question. Unfortunately it didn't get a lot of attention and as one of those "some users only (or primarily) use the "newest" view" I wonder how many other migrated questions I've missed seeing.

Comment: I'd say the right place for this feature request is MSE but since it didn't get much attention there, let's hope it gets picked up from here. I totally agree with your suggestion.